# how to download a specific version of selenium with pip

Tags: command-line, pip, selenium

I want to install `selenium` via a `requirements.txt` with `pip`.

So I put `selenium==2.53.0` into my `requirements.txt`.

However, when I do `pip install -r requirements.txt` it says

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement selenium==2.53.0 >(from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
No distributions at all found for selenium==2.53.0
```

even though on the [website](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) it says that this is the last version.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you just do `pip install selenium`, what version do you get?

Comment: how do I find that out? If I do `locate selenium` I get version 2.53.1 which also doesn't work

Comment: I'm using debian-7.9 for the BBB, is that maybe why?